# Solving $\sin(\theta) + \cos(\theta) = -1$ using the T-Formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

In class we've learned 2 methods for solving trigonometric equations.

1. T-Formula: If you're not familiar with the T-Formula look here; [T-Formula](http://www.trigonometry-help.net/half-angle-formula.php)
2. Auxiliary Method: If you're not familiar look [here](http://www.intmath.com/analytic-trigonometry/6-express-sin-sum-angles.php)

When I was trying to solve the equation $\sin(\theta) + \cos(\theta) = -1$, where $0 \leq \theta \leq 360$. When I used the auxiliary method I get the 2 answers of $180, 270$. But when I use the T-Formula I only get $270$. In the T-Formula I end up getting to the following equation:

$$\frac {2t + 1 - t^2}{1+t^2} = -1$$
$$2t+1-t^2 = -1-t^2$$
$$2t=-2$$
$$\therefore t=-1$$
But $t=\tan(\frac{\theta}{2})$, so...
$$\tan(\frac {\theta}{2}) = -1$$

But there $\theta \neq 180$ as $\tan(90)$doesn't exist. But that is one of the answers.

What am I doing wrong?
Why doesn't the T-Formula get all the answers (it should)?

Comment: I think you're not taking both the roots when solving for $\tan \frac{\theta}{2}$. there's a $\pm$ involved that you're missing I believe. I wish you'd show your work so I can comment more

Comment: Read the last paragraph of the link you posted: "This implies that some solutions are missing. Hence when t-formula is used, we have to check whether  are solutions.We can do this by substituting into the equation."

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. My teacher didn't tell us this

Comment: Why did this get marked as an exact duplicate? The "duplicate" asks about a different question and solves it using different methods (which is the problem of my question, the method isn't working)